# Polyline disappear on zoom out API Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

According to an old topic this problem should be fixed in version 2 of the API 
(https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=15)

Testing in Chrome v. 35.0.1916.153 and IE9 the bug appeared, already in Firefox v. 31 is working perfectly.

Codes to show the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/as0wv114/2/

```
  // HTML
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

//CSS
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

//JS
       var map;
    var latLngBounds;
    var coordinate = [];
    var flightPath = [];
    window.onload = initialize();

    function initialize() {

        /* Create Map */
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM,
            },
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-24.1207046509, -52.7306060791)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                  mapOptions);
        latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();    

        /* Create first polyline */
        coordinate[0] = new google.maps.LatLng('-24.1207046509', '-52.7306060791');
        coordinate[1] = new google.maps.LatLng('-24.1191787720', '-52.7316970825');
        coordinate[2] = new google.maps.LatLng('-24.1191864014', '-52.7337504883');   
        flightPlanCoordinates = [coordinate[0], coordinate[1], coordinate[2]];
        flightPath[0] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: flightPlanCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 8
        });

        /* Create second polyline */
        coordinate[3] = new google.maps.LatLng('-25.2782688141', '-50.0997734070');   
        coordinate[4] = new google.maps.LatLng('-25.2793374786', '-50.0998001099');   
        flightPlanCoordinates = [coordinate[3], coordinate[4]];
        flightPath[1] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: flightPlanCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 8
        });

        /* Set polylines in Map */
        flightPath[0].setMap(map);    
        flightPath[1].setMap(map);    

        /* Center polilynes in Map */
        $.each(coordinate, function(key, value){
            latLngBounds.extend(value);
        });
        map.fitBounds(latLngBounds);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/as0wv114/3/

```
  // HTML
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

//CSS
    html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

//JS
       var map;
    var latLngBounds;
    var coordinate = [];
    var flightPath = [];
    window.onload = initialize();

    function initialize() {

        /* Create Map */
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM,
            },
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-24.1207046509, -52.7306060791)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                  mapOptions);
        latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();    

        /* Create first polyline */
        coordinate[0] = new google.maps.LatLng('-24.1207046509', '-52.7306060791');
        coordinate[1] = new google.maps.LatLng('-24.1191787720', '-52.7316970825');
        coordinate[2] = new google.maps.LatLng('-24.1191864014', '-52.7337504883');   
        flightPlanCoordinates = [coordinate[0], coordinate[1], coordinate[2]];
        flightPath[0] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: flightPlanCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 8
        });

        /* Create second polyline */
        coordinate[3] = new google.maps.LatLng('-25.2782688141', '-50.0997734070');   
        coordinate[4] = new google.maps.LatLng('-25.2893374786', '-50.0998001099');   
        flightPlanCoordinates = [coordinate[3], coordinate[4]];
        flightPath[1] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: flightPlanCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 8
        });

        /* Set polylines in Map */
        flightPath[0].setMap(map);    
        flightPath[1].setMap(map);    

        /* Center polilynes in Map */
        $.each(coordinate, function(key, value){
            latLngBounds.extend(value);
        });
        map.fitBounds(latLngBounds);
    }
```

Since the code worked in Firefox v. 31, the problem would be in other browsers or is this a problem of the Google Maps API?

Sorry my english.

Comment: I can't find what causes this behavior. I have different examples of polylines that don't disappear on Chrome. I will test further.

Comment: One possible issue: google.maps.LatLng objects should have _numbers_ as arguments, not strings.  [Doesn't seem to fix the issue though](http://jsfiddle.net/as0wv114/4/)

Comment: Really  'geocodezip' the recommendation is number as argument, not  string. It is clear here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=724 but still does not solve as you said, I'm waiting for help, thanks.

Comment: I say a bug/feature. As you zoom out google map decided that your polygon is to small to display at that zoom level.

If you change your first point to be a big longer like so

coordinate[0] = new google.maps.LatLng('-24.1907046509', '-52.7306060791');

The maps shows it for longer when you scroll out.

Comment: Even google product on chrome has the same issue https://www.google.com/maps/d/ . Perhaps the canvas draw/webgl in chrome is doing this. I think you should open a bug report on this or reopen that old one. Annoying bug.

Comment: IE9 is no longer officially supported by the Google Maps JavaScript AP so bugs could appear, but Chrome should work. Strange behaviour. Did you receive an answer?

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed now.

Comment: I thought I might have been seeing this bug, but it turned out to be a zIndex issue where the lines were actually below a tiled image I was displaying on top of the map.